# HANA- Not able to delete full text index

Tags: hana

Hi all I have to drop a full text index.
On trying to run

DROP FULLTEXT INDEX index1;

I get Error: (dberror) [258]: insufficient privilege: Detailed info for this error can be found with guid 'fenfejf'

Further I tried to add permissions to this by modifying the .hdbrole file in the application used
by adding

"object_privileges":[ 
      { 
        "name":"index1", 
        "type":"INDEX", 
        "privileges":[ "SELECT","DROP" ]
      } 
    ]

But now I see this error,
 Error: com.sap.hana.di.role: "INDEX": no applicable privileges exist for this object type

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

INDEX is not an object type which can be used to define object privileges. It is an object privilege (as e.g. SELECT) which can be applied for schemas and tables (like described [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b3ee5778bc2e4a089d3299b82ec762a7/2.0.04/en-US/8978bfdfcf3b45f9acf3fdb0964d3d9c.html)). Given that privilege you are authorized to create, update or drop index objects.

Applying the privilege to a table would look like following for instance:

```
"object_privileges":[ { "name":"myTableName", "type":"TABLE", "privileges":[ "INDEX" ] }
```